# Reusable library to alert user of potentially unsaved changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, form

I wrote a small reusable component based of some of the examples to this question on Stack Overflow about [Activating `OnBeforeUnload` *only* when field values have changed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/925111/1366033).

It works like this:

- You can specify the portion of the page that it will use to listen for any data changes to input fields by adding the class `.alertChanges`.
- Since you'll occasionally want to leave the page for good reason when hitting save or cancel, you can avoid the extra popup by adding the class `.bypassChanges` to those elements.
- If anything other than a bypass change button attempts to leave the page (following another link / closing the browser), then the user will get an alert if there are unsaved changes.
- If there are no unsaved changes, they won’t get plagued by messages every time they try to navigate through the application.

Here's the code in a file AlertChanges.js which must come after jQuery:

```js
//####### Alert Changes ##################################################################
// Utilizes two classes:
// .alertChanges  - Will listen for changes on any :input child elements.
//                  If a change occurs, the user will be be prompted before navigating away
// .bypassChanges - Sometimes the user has already indicated they want to save any changes
//                  by clicking cancel or save.  Add this class so the user will not be
//                  bothered with an extra popup
// Note: cannot guarantee that the user didn't change a value and later revert it
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/6579437/1366033


// IIFE automatically runs
(function ($, window) {

    // jQuery Extension
    // The handler is executed at most once for all elements for all event types.
    $.fn.only = function (events, callback) {

        // add listener and save original collection as jQuery object
        var $this = $(this).on(events, myCallback);

        // when callback fires, remove event handler and raise passed in function
        function myCallback(e) {
            $this.off(events, myCallback);
            callback.call(this, e);
        }

        // return original collection
        return this;
    };


    // Wait for document ready
    $(function () {

        var $alerts = $(".alertChanges");

        // only run if we have an element of interest
        if ($alerts.length) {

            var needToConfirm = false;

            // check before leaving
            window.onbeforeunload = askConfirm;

            function askConfirm() {
                if (needToConfirm) {
                    return "Are you sure you want to navigate away? Any unsaved data will be lost.";
                }
            }

            // wait for any other page changes
            setTimeout(function () {
                needToConfirm = false;
                listenForChanges();
            }, 1000);

            // if any input element changes, we'll need to confirm exit
            function listenForChanges() {
                $alerts.find(":input").only('change', function () {
                    needToConfirm = true;
                });
            }

            // disable confirmation message for select elements
            $(".bypassChanges").click(function () {
                needToConfirm = false;
            });

        }

    });
})(jQuery, window);
```

Here's an example of a potential usage of this, but with the right classes, you can throw it on any page:

```html
<form method="get" class="alertChanges">
    <input type="text" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Save - Allow" class="bypassChanges" />
    <input type="submit" value="Go somewhere else - Warn"/>
</form>
```

#### [Here's a Demo in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HP1Rsl2cDFgFzCnPGcjS?p=preview)

You'll have to run the example in a new window in order to get the `onbeforeunload` event to fire.

I don't have a specific point of inquiry into the code.

The thing that feels hackiest is the timeout for other elements to load.  When a form loads, sometimes we'll modify certain elements based on others.  If that happens, I didn't want the page load changes in jQuery to be responsible for triggering the change event for this script.  One second seemed like enough time to let a script execute while not so much that a user has done any serious data entry that they would be remiss to inadvertently lose.

Comment: This doesn't work on some browsers, like (sadly) Opera 12.17. You should handle this kind of case some other way, if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a once over:

- From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload), you should *assign a string value to the returnValue property of the Event object and return the same string*, you only coded the latter part.
- I am not sure why you use a temporary variable for `onbeforeunload`, you could simpply

  ```
     // check before leaving
      window.onbeforeunload = function askConfirm(e) {
          if (needToConfirm) {
              return e.returnValue = 'Are you sure you want to navigate away? Any unsaved data will be lost.';
          }
      }
  ```
- For the hacky part, you could use the obsolete http://api.jquery.com/live/ or use the proper approach which is documented in that link as well. Waiting a second is wrong, especially when you think mobile.
- Other than that I really like the code. I understood it immediately, it is nicely compact and commented.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! It's funny that MDN doesn't use their reccomended sytax with `returnValue` in [their own example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload#Example).  In terms of using `.live` (or `.on`), I'm not sure how I'd be able to implement that in this example.  I need to give elements some breathing room from any changes that other scripts run when the page loads.  I could start by listening to them right away, but I would still need to have a cutoff point for changes made by javascript and those made by the user that I'd want to alert on.

Comment: Ah, I thought you worried about newly created elements not caught by `$(".alertChanges")`  I am not sure what to do for value initializing scripts.. Perhaps some stacktrace magic to distinguish scripts from genuine user input?